# Reading parquet file is slower in c++ than in python

Tags: python, c++, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have written code to read the same parquet file using c++ and using python. The time taken to read the file is much less for python than in c++, but as generally we know, execution in c++ is faster than in python. I have attached the code here -

```
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/reader.h>
#include <arrow/filesystem/localfs.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   // ...
   arrow::Status st;
   arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
   arrow::fs::LocalFileSystem file_system;
   std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> input = file_system.OpenInputFile("data.parquet").ValueOrDie();

   // Open Parquet file reader
   std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> arrow_reader;
   st = parquet::arrow::OpenFile(input, pool, &arrow_reader);
   if (!st.ok()) {
      // Handle error instantiating file reader...
   }

   // Read entire file as a single Arrow table
   std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table;
   auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   st = arrow_reader->ReadTable(&table);
   auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   if (!st.ok()) {
      // Handle error reading Parquet data...
   }
   else{
       auto ms_int = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (t2 - t1);
       std::cout << "Time taken to read parquet file is : " << ms_int.count() << "ms\n";
   }
}
```

The code i used in python is -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import time

start_time = time.time()

table = pq.read_table('data.parquet')

end_time = time.time()

print("Time taken to read parquet is : ",(end_time - start_time)*1000, "ms")
```

On running the c++ code for a file of size about 87mb, the output for  c++ is -

> Time taken to read parquet file is : 186ms

While for python the output is -

> Time taken to read parquet is :  108.66141319274902 ms

Why there is such a difference in time of execution for the function read_table in c++ and python ?

Comment: To get milliseconds, you need to multiply by 1000, not by 100.

Comment: Changed that, but still python is faster, 100 ms compared to 186ms, any possible reasons for that ?

Comment: My guess is that the python reader (which is most likely written in C or C++ also) is more frequently used and therefore has been better optimized. I’m not sure SO is the place to get a definite answer on this question though, you may want to contact the author of the slower api if it’s important to know.

Comment: Have you run these several times?  Perhaps there is a "cache warming" effect.

Comment: Not ran it several times, these are output for the first run after creating the 'data.parquet' file.

Comment: The python `read_table` is based on the exact same C++ APIs as you are using above. There are however several options you can specify / tune to improve performance, and the python  function might do this by default. For example, it will read the file in parallel by default (specify `use_threads=False` to disable this).

Comment: @SourabhKulhari -- Please provide the optimization settings you used to build the C++ program.   No C++ question that concerns speed should leave out this *very* important information.  If you're running an unoptimized or "debug" build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.   You should only be timing optimized (release) builds.

Comment: I used the following command to build g++ -O3 file_name.cpp -larrow -lparquet -o file_name

Comment: I don’t understand: how do you get the same time after multiplying the Python result by 1000 instead of 100?!

Comment: Man the result is same in terms that, after multiplying with 1000, the time of execution is still less for python than c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a comparison try this CPP code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/filesystem/api.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/reader.h>

using arrow::Result;
using arrow::Status;

namespace {

Result<std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader>> OpenReader() {
  arrow::fs::LocalFileSystem file_system;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto input, file_system.OpenInputFile("data.parquet"));

  parquet::ArrowReaderProperties arrow_reader_properties =
      parquet::default_arrow_reader_properties();

  arrow_reader_properties.set_pre_buffer(true);
  arrow_reader_properties.set_use_threads(true);

  parquet::ReaderProperties reader_properties =
      parquet::default_reader_properties();

  // Open Parquet file reader
  std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> arrow_reader;
  auto reader_builder = parquet::arrow::FileReaderBuilder();
  reader_builder.properties(arrow_reader_properties);
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(reader_builder.Open(std::move(input), reader_properties));
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(reader_builder.Build(&arrow_reader));

  return arrow_reader;
}

Status RunMain(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Read entire file as a single Arrow table
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table;
  for (auto i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto arrow_reader, OpenReader());
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(arrow_reader->ReadTable(&table));
    std::cout << table->num_rows() << "," << table->num_columns() << std::endl;
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ms_int =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
    std::cout << "Time taken to read parquet file is : " << ms_int.count()
              << "ms\n";
  }

  return Status::OK();
}

} // namespace

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Status st = RunMain(argc, argv);
  if (!st.ok()) {
    std::cerr << st << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then compare with this python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                                     
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import time

for i in range(10):
    parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('/home/pace/experiments/so4/data.parquet', pre_buffer=True)
    start_time = time.time()
    table = parquet_file.read()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Time taken to read parquet is : ",(end_time - start_time)*1000, "ms")
```

On my system after 10 runs a t-test fails to distinguish the two distributions (p=0.64).

Comment: While running the python script, there is an error encountered, unexpected keyword argument 'pre_buffer', then i looked into the Parquet File at the link - https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile and it mentions no argument with name pre_buffer. How to use pre_buffer for python ?

Comment: Ah, yes.  Looks like pre buffering wasn't fully supported in 4.0.0.  The arg will be there in 5.0.0.  You can try taking pre buffering out of both the C++ and python and you should still get similar results.

Answer (score 4):

The python `pq.read_table` is based on the exact same C++ APIs as you are using in your example (under the hood it is also using C++ `parquet::arrow::FileReader`), as both the Python and C++ APIs come from the same Arrow project.
So except for a tiny bit of Python call stack overhead, it would be expected that both ways will perform the same.

There are however several options you can specify / tune to improve performance, which can explain the difference in your case. For example, the python function will read the file in parallel by default (you can specify `use_threads=False` to disable this). The C++ FileReader on the other hand doesn't do this by default (check [`set_use_threads`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html#_CPPv4N7parquet5arrow10FileReader15set_use_threadsEb)). There might be other options that the python reader sets by default as well.
And in addition, the exact build flags when compiling your C++ example can also have an influence.

Comment: I used the set_use_threads command, arrow_reader -> set_use_threads(1) to turn on using multiple threads, it improved the performance for c++ as compared to using a single thread but the performance was not as good as in the case when we use multiple threads with python(python ~ 31ms, c++ ~ 75ms). Can you please run these on your own environment and tell me whether the numbers i am are getting correct or not ?

Comment: Also,I can't see any other optimizations that are used in python.

Comment: Prebuffering may be the explanation for the rest of the performance.  Try adding `set_pre_buffer` to true in addition to `set_use_threads`.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the Python module is bound to functions compiled in a language such as c++ or using cython. The implementation of the python module may thus have better performance, depending on how it reads from the file or processes data.

Answer (score 0):

1 second  is 1000 milliseconds. So the difference is not quite as large. That aside, many functions of python often utilize CPython, which puts them on a very even playing field. Then it just depends on how well the function is written and optimized. In this case, it is likely that the python function was more optimized than the C++ one was.

Comment: So if I am working with parquet files, using python is a better option than c++, right ? But for a project i was asked to get better performance using c++ and personally i think it is not possible to attain better performance using the in-built library function for read and write parquet.

Comment: @SourabhKulhari In this case, yes, python is the best choice. It is theoretically possible to achieve better performance in C++, but it is very difficult for you to do alone (unless there is some other pre-existing library implementation). 

Fact is, the library functions you use have been carefully brainstormed by people much smarter than you and me to be as efficient as possible. 
Although I suppose you could try and find how the python function has been implemented under the hood and maybe you could draw inspiration from that?